# Best tool for simple automated deployment with Django

Tags: django, deployment

For a Django project, I'm looking for a tool that would:

1. update the code on my server from a given branch in a remote repository (example: a master branch from Bitbucket)
2. run basic django command (migrate, collectstatic, etc...)
3. restart the project
4. notify me that all went ok (on Slack for instance)

I've seen many possible ways of doing this (Ansible, DeployBot, Pipelines, etc...), but I was wondering if there is a tool to recommend for a simple app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, on my Django project I am using Fabric (http://www.fabfile.org) for all activities mentioned by you. So deploy from particular branch, Django commands (eg. static collect), server restart etc.